# How to blur side of horizontal video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, blur

I would like to find a way to blur the top and the bottom of an horizontal video with the same video.

At the moment I have the code to do the opposite :

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=1920*2:1080*2,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=-1:1080[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=w=1920:h=1080" outpt.mp4
```

So I have this :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAoyw.png)
And I would like to have this :
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJlyD.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please format your code using the visual editor, or markdown syntax. Docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: It's done, thanks for the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, but the video is not center and I think it's not the good resolution because the video on the side is bigger than the other video.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=1080*2:1920*2,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=1080:-1[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=0:(H-h)/2,crop=w=1080:h=1920,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black" -s 1080x1920 outpt.mp4
```

Finally, I get that : [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbzS4.png)

Comment: I don't think this solution fixes the original problem, therefore you shouldn't post it as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).